# Work item distribution among workers using a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a table `Items`, which has a `BIT` column `InProcessing`.

There are multiple concurrent worker threads pulling items from the table.

How do I make sure the same item doesn't get pulled by multiple workers using the `InProcessing` column?

Do I have to use the SNAPSHOT isolation level and check for errors on `UPDATE`?

Can I get away without the SNAPSHOT isolation level? (SERIALIZABLE doesn't seem to work in this case: as far as I see a SELECT doesn't exclusively lock the selected rows, so 2 workers can select the same items and see them as

> InProcessing=0

before updating them)

Answer (score 1):

put the select in a transaction and do the select with the following hint:

```
begin transaction
select col1, col2 

from table1 with (updlock, holdlock)


where col3='123'
....
commit transaction
```